# React Native Android : Creating a simple module

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run the most basic React Native example where i am tring to change a text passed to a custom java module :

My index.android.js file :

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Image = React.Image;
var Button= require('react-native-button');
var NativeModules = React.NativeModules;
var TouchableNativeFeedback = React.TouchableNativeFeedback;

var Directory2 = React.createClass({
render: function() {
  var layout =
      <React.View style = { styles.parent } >
          <React.Text>
              Enter Host :
          </React.Text>

          <React.TextInput
              onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({input: e})}
              text = { this.state.input }
              onSubmitEditing = { this.showMeaning }
          />

          <Image source={ this.state.setImg } style={styles.img} />

          <Button
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this._handlePress}>
            Test
          </Button>
      </React.View>
  ;
  return layout;
},
getInitialState: function() {
return {
    input : '',
    setImg : require('image!red'),
    text: 'Goodbye World.'
};
},
showMeaning: function() {
  // Use the ternary operator to check if the word 
  // exists in the dictionary.
  var meaning = "you entered some text";

  // Update the state
  this.setState({
       output: meaning 
  });
},
_handlePress: function() {
  this.setState({
      setImg : require('image!green')
 });

  require('NativeModules').PingModule.processString( this.state.text, (text) => { alert(text); });
 },
 });

var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({

// For the container View
parent: {
    padding: 16
},

img : {
  alignSelf : 'flex-start'
},

button: {
  textAlign : 'center',
  backgroundColor : '#FF0000',
  width : 100,
  alignSelf : 'flex-end'
},

buttonText: {
  fontWeight: 'bold'
},
});

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('Directory2', function() {
   return Directory2;
});
```

My MainActivity.java file :

```
package com.directory2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import com.facebook.react.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

// Add extra packages here
import com.directory2.CustomPackages;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage()) // Add packages here!
            .addPackage(new CustomPackages()) // <-- and here
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "Directory2", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
    mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
  } else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}

@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this, this);
    }
}
}
```

My React package file :

```
package com.directory2;


import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomPackages implements ReactPackage {

@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
  List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
  modules.add(new PingModule(reactContext));
  return modules;
}

public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
  return Collections.emptyList();
}

public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
  return Collections.emptyList();
}

}
```

And my Module file :

```
package com.directory2;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;

public class PingModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

public PingModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }

// Available as NativeModules.MyCustomModule.processString
@ReactMethod
public void processString(String input, Callback callback) {
    callback.invoke(input.replace("Goodbye", "Hello"));
}

@Override
public String getName() {
  return "HelloWorld";
}
}
```

The project builds but when i click on "Test" button

> require('NativeModules').PingModule.processString( this.state.text, (text) => { alert(text); });

Above line throws error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require('NativeMobules').PingModule.processString')

Comment: Change "HelloWorld" in getName() to your export name, in this case "PingModule"

Comment: Thank You @kar this was the issue. I changed "HelloWorld" to "PingModule" and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to the end of PingModule -

```
export default PingModule;
```

You gotta export modules to make them usable.

Comment: You can call directly with NativeModules.PingModule.processString(), export not needed.

Comment: Interesting..., can you please link to any page where I can read more about this? Thanks.

Comment: "To make it simpler to access your new functionality from JavaScript, it is common to wrap the native module in a JavaScript module. This is not necessary but saves the consumers of your library the need to pull it off of NativeModules each time. This JavaScript file also becomes a good location for you to add any JavaScript side functionality." -- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. @kar  has answered the question.